# How do I assign callback paramaters without nesting

Tags: javascript

I like to write my callback functions in a private namespace and then call them by reference. eg

```
var myCallback = function() {

};

// ... somewhere else in the class.
SomeOtherObject.doSomething(myCallback);
```

This makes the code neater and more extendable. However when I need to pass any parameters to the callback from the original function it becomes messy and I have to enclose the callback reference in a closure. eg

```
var myCallback = function(a_var, another_var) {

};

// ... somewhere else in the class.
a_var = "something";
SomeOtherObject.doSomething(function(another_var) {
    myCallback(a_var, another_var);
};
```

This results in the callback requiring two function calls instead of one, creating overhead. It also means I have an undocumented anonymous function for the closure - or I document both functions. (It's not so much the missing function definition which is annoying as the parameter definitions.)  If the callback is small - as good functions are  - then it makes it seem not worthwhile to put it the private scope.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial application implementations allow you to pass variables in this way.

For example, using native [ES5's `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
SomeOtherObject.doSomething( myCallback.bind(null, a_var) );
```

*`another_var` will be passed to that function when called*

It's not supported everywhere though, so you can grab the one [from underscore](http://jsapi.info/underscore/default/bind/) and use that instead.

Comment: Won't `another_var` be `undefined` at the time when you execute `.bind`?

Comment: @xdazz, oh, you're correct. I don't think there's an easy way for the OP to avoid using an additional function wrapper then.

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot neater... even if behind the scenes it is still making two function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You could do function currying.

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    if (arguments.length<1) {
        return this;
    }
    var __method = this;
    var slice = [].slice;
    var args = slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
        return __method.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    }
}
```

then

```
var a_var = "something";
SomeOtherObject.doSomething(myCallback.curry(a_var));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about *curry'ing*. Actually, you can use ES5s `Function.prototype.bind` to accomplish that like so:

```
var myCallback = function(a_var, another_var) {
};

SomeOtherObject.doSomething(myCallback.bind(null, a_var, another_var);
```

What happens there is that `.bind()` takes the arguments and creates a *new function* and returning it, with the new scope and variables. Any other arguments which may get passed to `doSomething` will appear at the end of that bound list then.

The caveat in using `.bind()` is the performance. For some reason (which I didn't figure so far) its annoying slow. It doesn't really matter in your application since we are still talking about a couple of hundreds of thousands operations per second, but in comparison with a *normal* function, a bound function call gets slowed down by about 60-90%.

Comment: AFAIK, this is actually a case of partial application. Currying is a specific type of partial application where a *single* argument is passed to generated functions. See http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk

Comment: Filling in the first couple arguments of a function (and returning a new function) is typically called currying.

Comment: 'slowed down by about 60-90%.' That is better than the 50% that two normal nested function calls would generate.